# Laravel saml2 Issues after login, keeps redirecting

Tags: laravel, saml-2.0, laravel-saml

This was working and today it stopped all of a sudden and I'm not sure why or how to troubleshoot this.

This login was working for 6months+, but after the login form when I should be redirected to my page it keeps reloading and only displays the following on the screen.

```
Reference validation failed Redirecting to https://mypage.domain.com
```

I'm using version 2.1 of the "aacotroneo/laravel-saml2" package, I know it's been abandoned, I just found out today. Ideally, we would start using the other one but right now I'm more focused on getting the login working and then figuring out when to make the swap.

We changed all out certificates and keys and that thinking it had something to do with that but nothing changed and the redirect loop is still going.

The only other thing are these messages in the logs, but these are very vague

```
local.ERROR: Saml2 error_detail {"error":"Reference validation failed"} 
local.ERROR: Saml2 error {"error":["invalid_response"],"last_error_reason":"Reference validation failed"}
```

The person most familiar with this who did the setup is no longer around and the rest of us are not familiar with this package. I've been searching online but I haven't been able to find anything.

How can I troubleshoot this and what could be causing this problem?

Any additional information that is needed I'll add if asked, I'm not sure what would be useful.